# Apostrophe on MacBook Air

Tags: keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

How do I type an apostrophe `'` with a MacBook Air? My keyboard layout is set to Norwegian, and I have searched the keyboard character layout window without finding it. Am I just not seeing it, or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this shortcut myself, and came across your question. Just figured it out (on a norwegian keyboard). alt + @ = '

Answer (score 0):

the answer above is not the right one. alt + @ gives ` but not ' at least on my Macbook. My Python code needs a ' and I cannot find it either ...

I found an answer here
http://mostad.eu/tag/apostrophe/

> the Norwegian Macintosh keyboard layout does not correspond to the
>   physical Norwegian Macintosh keyboards on one key, which makes it
>   impossible to write apostrophes. All other glyphs and modifiers work
>   fine. My solution is to use the Norwegian [PC] keyboard layout and
>   remap the right command key (called the right Win key) to Alt-Gr with
>   the Keyboard system settings panel (as shown above).This makes the keys don’t 
>   match what is written on them, but since I am a touch typist used to
>   the PC keyobard on my netbook, I know where the discrepancies are and
>   can cope. Unfortunately, this also means that there is one more
>   keypress to write an upward or downward accent or the @, but on the
>   plus side: I can write apostrophes. When writing English, I really
>   need those for genitive and contractions. (In Norwegian we hardly ever
>   use them.)

Basically choose the regular "Norwegian" keyboard layout. This approach works for me. It also has the effect the "¨" key to create letters like "ö" works again. This does not work in the Macintosh layout as it should.

There is also the possibility to add a key manually:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions